# How to change parameter name in JSON response in Apex

Tags: apex

I am receving data from an external source. The response type is JSON and this is the sample format:

```json
[{BookName : "Abc" , desc:" book by great author" , BookPrice : "58" }, {BookName : "xzc" , desc:"This is the famous book" , BookPrice : "58" } ..............]
```

I wrote an Apex callout and got a response. I created a wrapper class to support that response.

```apex
Public class BookWrapper {
    Public string BookName; 
    Public string desc; //problem is here as the word desc is reserved keyword 
    Public string author; 
    Public string BookPrice;
}
```

In the above wrapper I can't have a variable name called "desc", as it's a reserved keyword.

Now it seems like I need to change the parameter in the response. From "desc" to "description", then only I can write the description variable in my wrapper class.

Any idea on how to change the parameter name in response in an Apex class? Or any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest resolution is to:

1. Replace the reserved character in response string: `desc` with `desc_x` or something.
2. Then have a property in response class with same name `public string desc_x`, for the deserialize to map data to that property.

Answer (score 0):

There are some missing quotes in sample JSON provided in the question.

Assuming that the JSON obtained from the external source is valid and contains the necessary quotes, like this:

`String jsonPayLoad= '[{"BookName" : "Abc" , "desc":"book by great author" , "BookPrice" : "58" }, {"BookName" : "xzc" , "desc":"This is the famous book" , "BookPrice" : "58" }]';`

Use `JSON.deserializeUntyped` method to deserialize the JSON to a list, then cast each item of the list into a map to extract the attributes, without the need for a wrapper class.

```
List<Object> listResponse = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonPayLoad);

for(Object obj: (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonPayLoad)){
  Map<String, Object> mapItem= (Map<String, Object>)obj;
  system.debug(mapItem.get('BookName') + ' ' + mapItem.get('desc'));
}
```